# Updating table value to null using EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 with Code First, I know how to create new value no problem and for the most part update existing data with new info but what I can't figure out is how to update an existing value to NULL. The situation is that I am removing the existing value that is in the DB, the column does allow NULL values. How do I tell EF to replace the current value of the column with a NULL value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to remove a complete record (row) from the database and are NULLing the value in every column?

Comment: Is the entity property defined as being nullable?

Comment: Did you try to assign a null value to the object's property and invoke `DbContext.SaveChanges()`? Object of course have to be traced by EF5 context.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the value of the property you want to make null, and save the changes:

```
var myRecord = dbContext.MyTable.First(...);
myRecord.MyColumn = null;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Of course, the data type of the property must be nullable -- e.g. `Nullable<int>` rather than `int`.

If you want to delete the entire record, use the `Remove` method provided by the collection:

```
var myRecord = dbContext.MyTable.First(...);
dbContext.MyTable.Remove(myRecord);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```